# Java was started but returned exit code =-1

Tags: anypoint-studio

Im getting "Java was started but returned exit code =-1" when launching anypoint studio 7.14.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fSA7.png)  . has anyone experienced this?

file path for JAVA_HOME is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kl49.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mentioned in the [documentation for configuring the JDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.14/change-jdk-for-studio-wx) for Anypoint Studio for Windows. Instead of using the environment variable JAVA_HOME you should configure the path to the JDK DLL in the anypointstudio.ini configuration file.

Also ensure you have installed a JDK and not just a JRE. You didn't provide enough details in the question but the path in the screenshot looks suspicious.

Example:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11+9\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Additionally ensure that you are using a JDK that matches the architecture of the version of Studio (32 bits or 64 bits). If your system supports 64 bits, like every modern computer do, then you should be using 64 bits Studio.